# Using scipy.interpolate in python, I want to erase certain values and interpolate them

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

In my code, I have certain values like

```py
my_list = [725.998474, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 789.507934, 792.585388, 801.612916, 799.38916, 809.280518, 809.186036, 811.899414, .... , 412.314528]
```

In my code, I want to interpolate the points where the list is 0.0 because they are outliers. But it is not working as interpolation only works for empty values.

How can I erase those 0.0 values and do interpolation?

Comment: Welcome JasonKim, could you add a code snippet, so we can better understand what you are trying to do and which packages you are using? scipy.interpolate.interp1d can interpolate any value, but the pandas interpolate method is there to fill na value. What are you exactly trying to do? Please edit your question accordingly :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is exactly 0 an outlier? Or is < 100 (say) an outlier? Decide that, then via predicate indexing form a new array that doesn't have those values; then call `interp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the data you provided, we can create a "cleaned" list of the x and y data using numpy. You said that the values equal to 0 are the outliers, but checking equality with floating point numbers can lead to issues, so I used `np.isclose`. With the outliers removed, you can interpolate the cleaned data.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

y = np.array([725.998474, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 789.507934, 792.585388,
              801.612916, 799.38916, 809.280518, 809.186036, 811.899414, 
              412.314528])
x = np.arange(len(y))

outliers = np.isclose(y, 0)
y_clean = y[~outliers]
x_clean = x[~outliers]

spline = make_interp_spline(x_clean, y_clean)
y_interped = spline(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_clean, y_clean, ".", label="cleaned", zorder=3)
ax.plot(x, y_interped, label="interpolated")
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
fig.show()
```

[image]

If, as @[Reinderien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313768/reinderien) suggested, your actual condition is that values below 100, for example, are outliers, then you could change it to that condition (i.e. `outliers = y < 100`).